# Undetected chromedriver "cannot connect to chrome at ... from chrome not reachable" on ubuntu 23.10 x64

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have a small webscrapping script built with selenium, most specifically the undetected chromedriver and python on a ubuntu droplet in digital ocean, but i'm running through some issues.

When i'm running this in my computer, it works all fine, my environment:

- Mac Os Catalina version 10.15.7
- Python3.11.5, pip24.0
- Selenium4.16.0, undetected_chromedriver3.5.5
- Both GoogleChrome and ChromeDriver versions are 122.0.6261.94 (altho i'm not really using the chrome driver in my script, was before but then deleted it for reassons i don't remenber but was still working)

The script:

```
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    import time
    from random import randint
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import time
    
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'
    chrome_options.add_argument('User-Agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', True)
    
    driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    try:
        driver.get('https://google.com')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Coudn't go to the website: ", e)
```

Environment in my digital ocean droplet:

- OS is Ubuntu 23.10 x64
- Python3.11.6, pip23.3
- Selenium4.18.1, Undetected_chromedriver3.5.5, webdriver-manager4.0.1
- Both GoogleChrome and ChromeDriver versions are 122.0.6261.94

Running locally this works 100%, but when i run in the DO droplet, it throws this error:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:46297
    from chrome not reachable
    Stacktrace:
    #0 0x55a2a485be93 <unknown>
    #1 0x55a2a4553b37 <unknown>
    #2 0x55a2a453ea13 <unknown>
    #3 0x55a2a458d601 <unknown>
    #4 0x55a2a458416b <unknown>
    #5 0x55a2a45cd71c <unknown>
    #6 0x55a2a45c0c53 <unknown>
    #7 0x55a2a4591db3 <unknown>
    #8 0x55a2a459277e <unknown>
    #9 0x55a2a48217cb <unknown>
    #10 0x55a2a48257e5 <unknown>
    #11 0x55a2a480f0e1 <unknown>
    #12 0x55a2a4826372 <unknown>
    #13 0x55a2a47f31bf <unknown>
    #14 0x55a2a484a488 <unknown>
    #15 0x55a2a484a683 <unknown>
    #16 0x55a2a485b044 <unknown>
    #17 0x7f656e497b5a <unknown>
```

Things i've tried to solve this:

- Adding some arguments to the chrome_options, such as --no-sandbox, --incognito, --headless=new, ...

```
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', True)
```

- Certifying that the chrome version installed in the machine "google-chrome --version", and the downloaded chromedriver is the same version. Both where downloaded from official sources.
- Using the commands bellow to uninstall and again installing the undetected_chromedriver:

```
    pip uninstall undetected_chromedriver
    pip install undetected_chromedriver
```

- Tried using xfvb

```
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
    vdisplay = Xvfb(width=800, height=1280)
    vdisplay.start()
```

- Tried explicitly calling the executable_path when calling the chrome instance, but didn't work.

This error is still persisting, any tips or help on how to solve this will be welcome, thanks in advance.